# Create a trigger that updates a column on one table when a column in another table is updated

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

i have two tables

Order(id, date, note)

and

Delivery(Id, Note, Date)

I want to create a trigger that updates the date in Delivery when the date is updated in Order.

I was thinking to do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Order
DECLARE
BEGIN
   UPDATE Delivery set date = ??? where id = ???
END;
```

How do I get the date and row id?

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How do i get the date and row id?

Assuming these are columns on your ORDER table called DELIVERY_DATE and ID your trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
    BEFORE UPDATE ON Order
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   if :new.delivery_date != :old.delivery_date
   then
       UPDATE Delivery d
       set d.delivery_date = :new.delivery_date
       where d.order_id = :new.id;
    end if;
END;
```

Note the FOR EACH ROW clause: that is necessary to reference values from individual rows.  I have used an IF construct to test whether to execute the UPDATE on Delivery.  If you have no other logic in your trigger you could write it like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
    BEFORE UPDATE OF delivery_date ON Order
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   UPDATE Delivery d
   set d.delivery_date = :new.delivery_date
   where d.order_id = :new.id;
END;
```

---

I have answered the question you asked but, as an aside, I will point out that your data model is sub-optimal.  A properly normalized design would hold DELIVERY_DATE on only one table: DELIVERY seems teh logical place for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit new and old reference in the trigger in the form of:
**REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW**

You can write to the :NEW value but not to the :OLD  value.

```
UPDATE Delivery set date = :new.delivery_date where id = :new.id;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "BUR_TABLENAME" BEFORE
UPDATE ON "TABLE" FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  If :new.active_date is not null Then
    :new.active_date := TRUNC(:new.active_date);
End If;
END;
```

**Template:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
 BEFORE
 UPDATE
 ON TABLE_NAME
 REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   V_VARIABLE   NUMBER (1);
BEGIN
   //Do Stuff;
  null;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the OLD and NEW bind variables. OLD references the row or column being updated before the change is made; NEW references it after the change.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig1
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON order  REFERENCING NEW AS new
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE delivery
       SET ddate   = :new.ddate
     WHERE id = :new.id;
END;
```

You can modify the `REFERENCING` clause to give your bind variables different names. You can include `OLD as <name>` too. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig1
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON order REFERENCING OLD AS old_values NEW AS new_values
    ...
```

If you don't want to change the default names of "old" and "new", you can leave out the `REFERENCING` clause completely.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a need for this kind of trigger, have a good look at your design. Is there really a need for a separate delivery record? Does an order really have more than 1 delivery ?

Triggers seem nice but they do tend to mess things up pretty quickly.