# How to create a table that automaticly updates another table when content is changed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What I try to accomplish is that I want to update rows in tableA when one row from tableB gets deleted.

The layout of tableA is this:

```
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| user_id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| nickname                   | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| password                   | varchar(129) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| mafia_id                   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

and of tableB this:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| mafia_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mafia_name  | varchar(32) | NO   |     |         |                |
| mafia_tag   | varchar(5)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| mafia_color | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| mafia_car   | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| mafia_base  | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to set all tableA.mafia_id to 0 when the corresponding mafia_id in tableB is deleted.

I read in the documentation that the database will automaticly do it for you, but you have to specify some stuff at table creation (in CREATE TABLE,  create_definition: | CHECK (expr)?). The documentation is a bit unclear to me.

I also read this topic:
[Create a trigger that updates a column on one table when a column in another table is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678102/create-a-trigger-that-updates-a-column-on-one-table-when-a-column-in-another-tab)

but this doesn't apply to me, i think?

So how would I create such a table (create table ...) or delete row statement?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using InnoDB, you can achieve this with a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tableA
  MODIFY mafia_id INT(11) NULL,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (mafia_id) REFERENCES tableB (mafia_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

As explained in the manual:

> - `SET NULL`: Delete or update the row from the parent table and set the foreign key column or columns in the child table to `NULL`. This is valid only if the foreign key columns do not have the `NOT NULL` qualifier specified. Both `ON DELETE SET NULL` and `ON UPDATE SET NULL` clauses are supported.
>
>   *If you specify a `SET NULL` action, make sure that you have not declared the columns in the child table as `NOT NULL`.*

Note that the constraint has the additional advantage of ensuring that `mafia_id` values in `tableA` must always reference an existing record in `tableB`.

Comment: what if the default mafia id is 0 (NOT NULL)? (primary keys start as 1)

Comment: @GamErix: `AUTO_INCREMENT` values can actually be made to start at any value you like; and even if a column is `AUTO_INCREMENT` one can still explicitly assign any value one likes to it (including the value `0`).  Therefore `0` has a different significance and meaning to `NULL`: `0` indicates a record in `tableB` with that id (does it exist?); whereas `NULL` in this case is the correct indicator for no associated record in the foreign table.  If you do want to refer to a record with id `0` rather than no matching record, you can either resolve that within your application or else use triggers.

Comment: when I try to add a record to tableA this happens:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`samp`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mafia_id`) REFERENCES `mafia` (`mafia_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)

Comment: @GamErix: What `mafia_id` were you trying to give that new record?  Does it exist in `tableB`?  See the "Note" at the bottom of my post.

Comment: ah okay I changed the default value of mafia_id to NULL instead of 0