# Mysql set values relative to other values?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a trigger that updates a column on one table when a column in another table is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678102/create-a-trigger-that-updates-a-column-on-one-table-when-a-column-in-another-tab)

I got a database table with these values

```
UpVotes | DownVotes | PercentVotes
8       | 2         | 80
10      | 0         | 100
5       | 5         | 50
560     | 34        | 94
```

is it possible to get the mysql database to work like this:

```
UpVotes | DownVotes | PercentVotes
8       | 2         | (UpVotes/(UpVotes + DownVotes)) x 100 = 80
10      | 0         | (UpVotes/(UpVotes + DownVotes)) x 100 = 100
5       | 5         | (UpVotes/(UpVotes + DownVotes)) x 100 = 50
560     | 34        | (UpVotes/(UpVotes + DownVotes)) x 100 = 94
```

automatically without having to update it via any script? Just like in excel when you can then change the UpVotes value or DownVotes value and the PercentVotes value automatically becomes the new correct percent of upvotes according to the total votes.

Sorry for my bad english but i hope you get my point. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `trigger` for that. Something like this:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER calc_percentages BEFORE INSERT on your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.PercentVotes = NEW.UpVotes/(NEW.UpVotes + NEW.DownVotes);
END
|
delimiter ;
```

It will run on every insert and add the calculated value. If you want it to update after an `update` then just add another trigger for `after update` instead of `before insert`.

Since the percentage information is a calculated value you can calculate it in your selects on-the-fly and don't store it in your DB. But if you really need the performance gain then use a trigger to store it.

Comment: Why did you choose to do it `BEFORE INSERT` rather than, say, `AFTER UPDATE`? Is the latter not available?

Comment: It is just an example. It can be `after update`, `after insert` or both. I chose `before insert` in my example.

Comment: You should manipulate the Inserted data instead of updating the table. I think your example won't work because the data is just not there (BEFORE INSERT) when you try to update it! You also should not forget to have an UPDATE Trigger, too!

Comment: @Pesse: Please don't try to edit other people's answers if you think it should be different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I keep getting this error when trying to run the script: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter | CREATE TRIGGER calc_percentages AFTER UPDATE on videos F' at line 1" and i can't seem to get it working. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The error says that there is a problem at the very first start of the script. How are you executing it? There seems to be a general problem.

Comment: I executed the script successfully by myself.

Comment: <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("...","...","...");
 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("mybase", $con);
 
 $sql = "delimiter |
     CREATE TRIGGER calc_percentages AFTER UPDATE on videos
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
      SET NEW.VideoVotesPercent = NEW.VideoVotesUP/(NEW.VideoVotesUP + NEW.VideoVotesDOWN);
     END
     |
     delimiter;";
 
 mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: oh, it looked kind of weird when i sent it directly like this. I'm new on this site

Comment: I'm not a PHP guru, but I don't think you can execute that in PHP like a normal query. It contains more than 1 query. That are 3 queries actually. So try to execute it in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH JUERGEN! I got it to work! A thousand thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to run something like this on the select, you may need to check the math though.

```
select UpVotes, DownVotes ((UpVotes / (UpVotes + DownVotes)) * 100) as PercentVotes from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
You can use triggers. Just set trigger on update and insert and it will change value of column.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using triggers then try something like this

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insertPercentVotes AFTER INSERT ON YourTableName

// calculate percentage here
      // Execute Update query here  
 END;
|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_votepercent BEFORE INSERT ON votetable FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.PercentVotes = (NEW.UpVotes/(NEW.UpVotes+NEW.DownVotes)) * 100  
  END;//

CREATE TRIGGER upd_votepercent BEFORE UPDATE ON votetable FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.PercentVotes = (NEW.UpVotes/(NEW.UpVotes+NEW.DownVotes)) * 100 
  END;//
```

See [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/trigger-syntax.html)