# Update Table 1 if update or delete happens in another Table

Tags: sql

I have two tables namely futureOrder_Table and orders. I want to update the date field in  futureOrder_Table table when there is a update or delete in order table delivery column. Basically if the order table date changes i also wanna change it in futureTable

Comment: Learn about triggers.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678102/create-a-trigger-that-updates-a-column-on-one-table-when-a-column-in-another-tab?rq=1 and also post which DBMS your on, so that some-one might come up with a proper example.