# Two tables, update specific columns and/or insert new record if doesnt exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: **NewData** and **RecentData**

```
      NewData

id | Order_Number | Company | SerialNumber | ShipDate
-----------------------------------------------------
 1 | 2323         | Apple   |  SN2324      | 2018-09-12 00:00:00
 2 | 53444        | Telsa   |  SN9098      | 2018-09-12 00:00:00
 3 | 42321        | Stack   |  SN9999      | 2018-09-12 00:00:00



      RecentData

id | Order_Number | Company | SerialNumber | ShipDate
-----------------------------------------
 1 | 2323         | Apple   |              | 2018-05-05 00:00:00
 2 | 53444        | Telsa   | oldserial    | 2018-07-20 00:00:00
```

When the *ShipDate* has changed on the **NewData** table, i need to **update** ONLY the *ShipDate* and *SerialNumber* columns on the RecentData table. Also if the Order_Number does exist on the NewData table but DOESNT exist on the RecentData table, add the entire row to the RecentData table.

I tried the following:

```
UPDATE RecentData
LEFT JOIN NewData on NewData.Order_Number = RecentData.Order_Number
SET RecentData.Order_Number = NewData.Order_Number;
```

But this removes the ordernumber's in Order_Number column.

Please help!

Comment: Hello, Welcome your requirement could be achieved by Trigger for updating table "RecentData" table on update "NewData" table.

Comment: How? Please elaborate?

Comment: Please take reference of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678102/create-a-trigger-that-updates-a-column-on-one-table-when-a-column-in-another-tab

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for a solution of your task. What a way is better depend on your project specific.

**Way 1:**
You can create a primary key by 'Order_Number' column and use 'ON DUPLICATE KEY' construction, for example:

```
INSERT INTO RecentData (Order_Number, Company, SerialNumber, ShipDate)
  (SELECT Order_Number,
          Company,
          SerialNumber,
          ShipDate
   FROM NewData) ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE RecentData.SerialNumber = NewData.SerialNumber,
   RecentData.ShipDate = NewData.ShipDate;
```

**Way 2:**
You can use two query: first query to update existing data and second query to insert new data. For example first query:

```
UPDATE RecentData
RIGHT JOIN NewData ON NewData.Order_Number = RecentData.Order_Number
SET RecentData.SerialNumber = NewData.SerialNumber,
    RecentData.ShipDate = NewData.ShipDate
WHERE NewData.ShipDate > <last_updating_date>
```

For example second query:

```
INSERT INTO RecentData (Order_Number, Company, SerialNumber, ShipDate)
  (SELECT Order_Number,
          Company,
          SerialNumber,
          ShipDate
   FROM NewData
   WHERE ShipDate > <last_updating_date> AND order_number NOT IN
       (SELECT order_number
        FROM RecentData))
```

**Way 3:**
You can create trigger on UPDATE event, for example:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER mytgigger BEFORE UPDATE ON NewData
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (old.ShipDate <> new.ShipDate) THEN
        SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RecentData WHERE order_number = new.order_number);
        IF cnt > 0 THEN
            UPDATE RecentData
            SET RecentData.SerialNumber = NewData.SerialNumber,
                RecentData.ShipDate = NewData.ShipDate
            WHERE order_number = new.order_number;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO RecentData (Order_Number, Company, SerialNumber, ShipDate)
            VALUES (new.Order_Number,
                new.Company,
                new.SerialNumber,
                new.ShipDate);
        END IF;
     END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Sometimes there's multiple records with the same order_number. For example, if the company purchased multiple equipment, the order_number will have a record for with the same order_number for each serial number of the equipment. I'm thinking the 3rd way might be the best way...